# Has anyone managed to make react-native-device-info with react-native 0.58?

Tags: react-native, react-native-device-info

I am trying to get the deviceid with `react-native-device-info`.
I started with an empty expo project which I ejected.

I imported the library, I also linked it.
But then I get gradle errors in android studio.

Have anyone managed to make it working. Can you tell which version you use?

Error from comments:

```
:ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0. 1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. 
Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown. 
Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[ 15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.2.0
```

Comment: What errors did you get ?

Comment: I user `"react-native-device-info": "^0.24.3"` with `"react-native": "0.57.1",` I remember having a really hard time installing it, can you show us the error u get?

Comment: If you are starting with an empty project, wouldn't you be better to create your project with `react-native init`? Also you should post your error messages as it may lead to the source of your problem

Comment: i used "expo init" to create the project as it replaces react-native-init.

Comment: here ise the error i am getting in Android studio :ERROR: In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[15.0.
1]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

Dependency failing: com.google.android.gms:play-services-flags:15.0.1 -> com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@[
15.0.1], but play-services-basement version was 16.2.0.